# Google Places radius search and geocoder

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm currently making a website using the Google Maps API and the Google Places library. When I first made it without the Google Places function, the map works fine. But when I added the functions for Google Places that part doesn't work. The code is here:

```
function initialize ()
{
var start = new google.maps.LatLng(54.00, -3.00);

var service;

var mapOptions = { 
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
  center: start,
  zoom: 4
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var address = $("#ilocation").val();

var coords;



geocoder.geocode({'address': address},
    function(results, status) {
        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
        {
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            document.write(bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location));
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                position:results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map
            }
            );

        }

coords = results[0].geometry.location;

    }

);

alert(coords);

var request = {
location: coords,
radius: '500',
types: ['store']
};

service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

function callback(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  var place = results[i];
  createMarker(results[i]);
}
}
}

function createMarker(place) {
var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
map: map,
position: place.geometry.location
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
infowindow.setContent(place.name);
infowindow.open(map, this);
});
}

};
```

I don't have a lot of experience with javascript so it could be something pretty simple that I'm missing. Thanks.

Comment: The error that comes up in my console says "Cannot read property of 'PlaceServices' of undefined, but I defined my map at the top

Comment: have you loaded the google place service library? `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places` And have you  created a `createMarker` function?

Comment: I have the library but I don't have a createMarker function. Why do I need a marker?

Comment: I'm sorry I actually do have createMarker, it's the last line of code.

Comment: because you have called it in your code `createMarker(results[i]);'. i think the purpose of this function is to create a marker

Comment: you could find the function here : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search. And please let us know that your problem is solved

Comment: Ah you're right, silly mistake. It actually didn't fix the problem though

Comment: could you please let me know the `$("#ilocation").val()` value

Comment: ilocation is an address typed into a text box on the site. In the tests I was using "12 Crest View Ct". I don't think that's the problem tho, that part of the site worked fine until I tried to institute a radius search

Comment: no just asked for testing purpose

Comment: I found other problems and updated small parts of the code earlier, here's my new code:

Comment: I think part of the problem is that in 'var request' the 'location' field is undefined because the values returned in the geocoder are out of scope

Comment: I've also updated to my latest code above

Comment: The new console error says "missing parameter: you must specify a loction"

Comment: @Nouphal.M I just got it to work, it was a scope problem. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Geocoder gets you the location from the text string, now you have to pass this location information to your places functionality. I have wrapped the google places code inside a function and call it from geocoder.

```
..................
var address = '12 Crest View Ct';

geocoder.geocode({'address': address},
    function(results, status) {
        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
        loc = results[0].geometry.location;

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            document.write(bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location));
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            new google.maps.Marker({
                position:results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map
            });
        place(loc); //here is the function call
        }

    }
);
```

Now the place function is as below :

```
function place(loc){
    var request = {
    location:  new google.maps.LatLng(loc.pb, loc.qb),
    radius: '500',
    types: ['store'],
    //keyword: address

    };

    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

    function callback(results, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
     for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      createMarker(results[i]);
     }
    }
    }

    function createMarker(place) {
     console.log(place) 
      var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(place.name);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
      });
    }

}
```

I have created a working demo [here](http://jsbin.com/UlALUXuG)
Go to the top right bottom of the page and click on Edit JS BIn to see the source code. Hope this helps...

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. I had just figured the same thing out. Thanks!